# Customize vim-latex to write file prior to compilation

Tags: compiling, vim

`<leader>ll` compiles the current file, but I'd like it to also write the current file before it does that. Personally, I don't understand why this is not default behavior. When would one ever wish to make some changes and then not have them included in their next compile?

I've tried adding `exec 'w'.mainfname` to vim-latex's main compile function `Tex_CompileLatex()`, which is defined in `compiler.vim`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not a specialist at all but here is the solution I have found for myself:
Write a function (for instance in `.vim/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim` ) and call it with an other key.

```
function! SaveAndCompile()
    write 
    call Tex_CompileLatex()  "defined in latex-suite/compiler.vim
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>f :call SaveAndCompile()
```

Of course you can change `<Leader>f` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but you could just use the normal vim command-line history to quickly write and compile a file from `vim` with one command similar to the following:

```
:w| ! xelatex %
```

Once that is the last command starting with `:w` in your command-line history you can write and compile your file in just four keystrokes: (Assuming you're in normal mode):

1. :
2. w
3. [arrow up]
4. enter.